# Are arrays really Objects?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

See the code below -

```
class test {
  public static void main(String args[]){
      int[] somearray = {1, 2};
      printarray(somearray);
  }

  static void printarray(Object[] array){
      System.out.println(array[0]);
  }
}
```

The above code will not compile since the `printarray` method cannot accept primitive arrays.
Or is this an auto-boxing limitation? If so, then I consider this a BIG limitation.

Comment: An array *is* an object, however an array of primitives is not compatible with an array of `Object`s, because primitives aren't objects, and auto-boxing can't handle that conversion.

Comment: "Above code will not compile since printarray method cannot accept primitive arrays." - No, the code won't compile because you haven't specified a type for `args`. Change it to `String[] args` and it compiles fine. Please edit it to be the *actual* code you wanted us to consider, that produces the error message you're interested in.

Comment: @JonSkeet It didn't compile for me on 1.6.0_45 even with the main method signature corrected, is this something that now works in 1.7/1.8?

Comment: Let me edit the question. I missed that part.

Comment: @JonK: Should be fine - what's the problem? Bear in mind that the code (as posted) doesn't *call* `printarray`...

Comment: @JonSkeet On 1.6, trying to call `printarray` results in `The method printarray(Object[]) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (int[])`

Comment: I also tried Object[] arrayIntObject = arrayInt; to create "autoboxed" object. This is not supported then why does this work: int x = 1; Object one = x;

Comment: You don't auto-box an array, you auto-box the individual elements inside the array, which is why your second example works.

Comment: @JonK: But the code posted didn't *try* to call `printarray`. It does now, but it didn't until just now.

Comment: @JonK: I know but the basic thing I am trying to understand is why autoboxing doesn't *work* with it. It seems autoboxing is an incomplete feature. Why are we making a grand declaration saying 'Arrays are Objects'. That is very generalized statement which is not true in all cases. The statement should be *'Object Arrays are Objects'*. ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet No, but I copied the code into Eclipse and added the call in myself (and fixed main's signature at the same time). It doesn't seem to want to work on 1.7.0_67 or 1.8.0_11 either.

Comment: Sorry, i missed calling the method. I had like 4 different copies of code I was testing.

Comment: @JonK: Right, so having *changed* the code, it doesn't compile. I was trying to make it clear to the OP that they should be posting the *actual* code they wanted us to compile - which wasn't the case. (The method call was missing and the parameter wasn't declared properly.)

Comment: Arrays themselves *are* objects. It seems like you're confusing what an array *is* and what that array *contains*.

Comment: Yup, that's why it's important to take your time when asking a question, and make sure you're really posting the code you want to post. In future, it would be helpful to include the error you're seeing as well, and ideally follow normal Java naming conventions too.

Comment: @JonK: Yes it did. The code posted at the time when I posted that comment compiled fine when you changed the parameter to `String[] args`. Bear in mind that that comment was posted 15 minutes before the question was changed to include the call to `printarray`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yup, ignore my previous, I was still thinking about the 'fixed' version with the method call added, rather than the code as it was posted (I was just about to delete that comment when you replied!)

Answer (score 4):

About your question title "Are arrays really Objects?": yes, they are.

About the problem you describe: an array of primitive types is not an array of objects (as an `int` is not a `java.lang.Object`).

To make your code work, you can declare your array like this:

```
Integer[] somearray = {1, 2};
```

Instead of using the primitive type `int`.

Note that some boxing is into effect here.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. `Are Arrays really Objects?`

Comment: You are right @ChetanKinger , but perhaps that's not really the key point of the question. Anyways, there it goes.

Comment: This is a bit dangerous though since it is still an Integer-array and not an Object-array. Attempting to put anything other than an Integer inside the array will throw an ArrayStoreException.

Answer (score 0):

> Are arrays really Objects?

Arrays are *dynamically* created objects, and they serve as a container that hold a (constant) number of objects of the same type. It looks like arrays are not like any other object, and that's why they are treated differently.

Your code *will* compile if you fix your `main` signature to:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

It'll not compile if you add `printarray(somearray)`, because `somearray` is an array containing `int`, where `printarray` (that should be named `printArray`) is a method accepting array of `Object`.

There are many solutions for your problem, one of them is changing `someArray` to be of type `Integer[]`.

Comment: `Above code will not compile since printarray method cannot accept primitive arrays`. I don't believe you have answered the question yet.

Comment: @ChetanKinger I answered the title. Will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are `Object`. Actually in java world every non primitive type is `Object.` Because each class you create is directly or indirectly the subclass of `Object (java.lang.Object)`.

Look the following code snippet -

```
int[] intArray = new int[10];
Object anObject = intArray; //valid assignment
Object[] objArray = intArray; //invalid assignment.
```

Here `intArray` is itself an `Object`. So it can be assigned with an `Object`. But `intArray` is not not an array of `Object` that is - `Object[]`.
So we can not assign `intArray` to `Object[]`.

Answer (score 0):

think of this way:

int is NOT `Object`, its `primitive data type`

thus `int[]` is not the same as `Object[]`

if you want to keep you `printarray` method the same, then 
you should change your `somearray` to `Integer` (Object representing of integers)

e.g.

```
Integer[] somearray = {1, 2};
printarray(somearray);
```